# Call WCF Service from another decoupled WCF service on the same site without HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a plugin model architecture that creates my Restful WCF services.

(It will be a couple years before we move to Web Api from WCF so, moving to Web Api isn't exactly a solution.)

I have decoupled WCF Microservices that don't reference each other.

- EntityAWebService
- EntityBWebService

EnityAWebService knows that a service EntityBWebService exists from a configuration, but doesn't reference it.

EntityAWebService and EntityBWebService are plugins. As such, they could be on loaded on the same site.

EntityAWebService makes a call to EntityBWebService using configuration information. The EntityBWebService could be on the same server or a different server. 
 - If on a different server, the code will continue to use HttpClient.
 - If on the same server, go cract the message and send it through the channel without going through HttpClient, operating system's network, and IIS.

Below is the architecture. The orange is what I want to create.

[image]

Using HttpClient means EntityAWebService sends a message that is going to hit the operating systems network layer and go through IIS. Neither of which is necessary. It causes performance issues, and as the Entity plugins increase, so does the number of sockets and even using a singleton httpclient, the sockets are leaking.

The orange in the architecture is what doesn't exist yet.

The code knows the Url to call for Entity B Web Service, the message content, and the headers. How would I simulate, in the code represented by the orange box, what IIS does to forward the call through the behaviors and to the Endpoint?

FYI, my current project is too complex to post, so I will create a sample and post it soon.

Sample project: https://github.com/rhyous/DecoupledWcfServices

Comment: It's been ages since I worked on WCF so I may be missing the point, but isn't that a matter of configuring the local WCF service to use a non-http binding (named pipes is probably best for server-local communication) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/choosing-a-transport

Comment: I've been researching this for days. Somehow, IIS sends the message. I just need to find out how and simulate it. I read a few articles by @carlosfigueira. I also found a LocalChannel in WCF examples, but it isn't exactly right.

Comment: named pipes would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to use named pipes. However, investigating how to use named pipes taught me what I needed to know. I just needed to use reflection and ChannelFactory. As the ChannelFactory for IIS hosting already exists, named pipes would be redundant.

Example Project here: https://github.com/rhyous/DecoupledWcfServices

And the appropriate snippet (the meat of the solution) is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace DecoupledWcfServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Service 1 and Service 2 are in the same namespace in this project
    /// </summary>
    public class MessageBus
    {
        public string CallOtherWcfService(string url, object content, NameValueCollection headers)
        {
            var service = GetServiceName(url);
                try
            {
                var netPipeUrl = $"http://localhost:54412/{service}/{service}.svc";
                var serviceContractType = typeof(IService2);
                var genericChannelFactoryType = typeof(WebChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(serviceContractType);
                var binding = new WebHttpBinding();

                var channelFactory = Activator.CreateInstance(genericChannelFactoryType, binding, new Uri(netPipeUrl)) as WebChannelFactory<IService2>; // I actually won't know it is an IService2 in my project, but getting this far should be enough
                var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel() as IService2; 
                using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
                {
                    var task = proxy.GetData("some data"); // Might need more work here to know which method to call based on the Url
                    task.Wait();
                    return task.Result; // Serialized JSON
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        internal string GetServiceName(string url)
        {
            var index = url.IndexOf(".svc");
            var sub = url.Substring(0, index);
            index = sub.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
            var sub2 = url.Substring(index, sub.Length - index);
            return sub2;
        }
    }
}
```